# Floating toolbar in left Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oEpK.png)
Im using angular material toolbar , i want to float a span inside the toolbar in left , i tried the css float left and it doesn't work 
anyhelp please

```
<mat-toolbar>

        <span>left</span>
        <span style="text-align: right;">  right </span>

</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with Flex Layout you can include [Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). For that the code goes like this :

```
<mat-toolbar fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlexFill>
<div class="branding">
    <div class="logo">Left</div>
</div>
<div fxFlex>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="end center"> Right</div>
</div></mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want:

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <div style="text-align: right; width:100%">
    <span style="float:left;">left</span>
    <span>right </span>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

In your code `text-align: right;` is useless because your `span` fit the content.